# Advice on k fold cross validation

Tags: python, svm, cross-validation

I am currently carrying out a cross validation method with support vector machine classification of dicom images using the code:

```
    #Cross Validation using k-folds
    clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf,X,Y,cv=16))
    print scores
    print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(),scores.std()*2))
```

As you can see, I am currently using 16 folds, how would I find out the best amount of folds to use? Is it a case of more is better?

Also, I have found that whilst using cross validation, my accuracy scores vary massively from 66% to 100% which usually give a mean accuracy of 82% - 85%. Is there any advice on how I could improve this and perhaps ensure the classifier is picking equal amount of images from each class?

Sorry, I'm very new to Python!

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

try using GridSearchCV. for example i can create a pipeline such as

```
pipeline = Pipeline([

    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
    ])

    parameters = {

        'clf__C': (0.1, 1, 10, 20, 30)
    }
```

so, here i am providing 5 different options for the C parameter of my LogisticRegression() classifier which is denoted by clf in my pipeline

of course, instead of LogisticRegression() you can use SVC. then

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3, verbose=1, scoring='accuracy')
```

then just something like

```
bestParameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print ('\t %s: %r' % (param_name, bestParameters[param_name]))
```

will give you the best set of options to specify